# IIS logs must-have basics on kibana dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard, elastic-stack, iis-logs

I'm implementing ELK to controll my servers. What visualizations do you think are basic to create a generic dashboard for iis logs.
There's any kind of market or example's page for kibana dashboards?
Thanks

Comment: See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-iis.html. This module deploys a sample dashboard that monitors basic metrics like response codes, response times, errors etc which provide a good picture of how IIS/ app health.

Comment: This sample dashboard is basic

Comment: Well, yes. Isn’t that enough to get started and you can add on top of the sample one to suit your needs ?